# making a list of dates and stock prices into a dictionary using date as a key and converting prices into floats-python

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I am creating a program where the user enters a file name. The file apple.dat has all the dates and stock prices apple. Right now I have all the data into one list. I need some help getting the list into a dictionary and using date (keep as string) as the key and making the stock prices into float values.

apple.dat file

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2020-01-02,74.059998,75.150002,73.797501,75.087502,74.333511,135480400
2020-01-03,74.287498,75.144997,74.125000,74.357498,73.610840,146322800
```

output I get

```
['2020-01-02,74.059998,75.150002,73.797501,75.087502,74.333511,135480400\n', '2020-01-03,74.287498,75.144997,74.125000,74.357498,73.610840,146322800\n'...]
```

code

```
def createdict(file_name):
  with open('apple.dat','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:]
  return lines
 

def main():
  print("Welcome to the Stock Price Program")
  print()
  file_name=input("Enter the data file name: ")

  list=createdict(file_name)
  print(list)
```

Comment: Python has a built in library for reading and writing CSV files. [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file (3 or so lines) you're reading (including the first line (the header).

Comment: @ChrisCharley, I have added a few lines of the text file

Comment: I am also trying to create a function so i can compute the average daily high for the year. Also, determining the lowest daily opening price for the year

Comment: Yea, i do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt this solution for your problem.

```py
import csv

def dict_date(file):
    dict1={}
    with open(file,'r') as file:
        for i in csv.DictReader(file):
            date=i.get('Date')
            i.pop('Date')
            row=i
            dict1[date]=row
    return dict1
file='t.csv'
res=dict_date(file)
print(res)
# {'2020-01-02': {'Open': '74.059998', 'High': '75.150002', 'Low': '73.797501', 'Close': '75.087502', 'Adj Close': '74.333511', 'Volume': '135480400'}, '2020-01-03': {'Open': '74.287498', 'High': '75.144997', 'Low': '74.125000', 'Close': '74.357498', 'Adj Close': '73.610840', 'Volume': '146322800'}}
```

Comment: Do I have to use the csv module and is there a way to do it without using the built in dictreader function

Comment: It's the easier way

Comment: Any ideas as to how I can do it without?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the csv library (specifically the `DictReader` constructor). It makes the solution simpler to address the fieldnames by name rather than addressing them by column number.

```
import csv

apl_stk = list()

with open('apple.dat', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for dictionary in reader:
        apl_stk.append(dictionary)

def avg(L, field):
    return sum(map(lambda x: float(x[field]), L)) / len(L)

def minimum(L, field):
    return min(map(lambda x: float(x[field]), L))


print(f"Avg. high: {avg(apl_stk, 'High'):.6f}")
print('minimum open:', minimum(apl_stk, 'Open'))
```

For your sample input data, this prints:

```
Avg. high: 75.147500
minimum open: 74.059998
```